# How to Use PayPal to Charge a Commission

Tags: paypal, wordpress

I have a plugin in wordpress like ebay where people can post their products and sale their products and i manage to save paypal response in my database. may i know how can I configure Paypal so that when someone sells something I get a percentage commission. I have searched everywhere, I haven't found anything. tnx

Answer (score 0):

You need to become a paypal partner, then you can put your BN code into the PayNow button you generate.

https://www.paypal-marketing.com/emarketing/partner/na/program/index.html

Comment: If you are wanting a commission of the sale (not of the paypal transaction), this is not possible. PayPal only handles a 1-1 payment transaction. Commission is a separate 1-1 transaction that you will need to handle another way.

Comment: sorry for the late reply i just woke up anyways. what i want is a commision of the sale when the customer buy the product their is a calculation for the commision and when the customer paid in paypal the commission will be send to another paypal account and the other will in the owner of the product paypal because that is one of the requirements of my plugin.

Comment: That is not possible with Paypal.